# How do I pull this value out of a closure to update a cutom Object in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, object, closures, google-cloud-firestore

I am building am application with a Firestore back end, and I am trying to call a document down with the current user's info for their settings page. I am able to do this no problems when updating an empty array, but am having a terrible time trying to populate a single document. I have a custom object called `DxUser`:

```
struct DxUser {
    var email:String?
    var name:String?
    var timeStamp:Date?
    var profileImageURL:String?
    var ehr: String?

    var dictionary:[String:Any]? {
        return [
            "email":email,
            "name":name,
            "timeStamp":timeStamp,
            "profileImageURL":profileImageURL,
            "ehr": ehr as Any

        ]
    }
}


extension DxUser : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let email = dictionary["email"] as? String,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date,
            let profileImageURL = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as? String,
            let ehr = dictionary["ehr"] as? String else {return nil}

        self.init(email: email, name: name, timeStamp: timeStamp, profileImageURL: profileImageURL, ehr: ehr)
    }
}
```

In the view controller, I am trying to update this variable with the current user, but I can only grab it in the closure, and it populates as nil anywhere outside the block. Here is the basic code I am using, but can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
class SettingsController: UIViewController {

var dxUser = DxUser()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    fetchUser()
}

func fetchUser() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

    userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            self.dxUser = DxUser(dictionary: (document?.data())!)!
            self.navigationItem.title = self.dxUser.name
            print (self.dxUser)
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, this is how I am doing it on the table view, but I didn't see anything comparable on the regular VC.

```
db.collection("users").document(uid!).collection("goals").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            //set the profile array to equal whatever I am querying below
            goalsArray = snapshot!.documents.flatMap({Goal(dictionary: $0.data())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much about the *location* of where you can access dxUser.  It's the *timing*.  Firebase APIs are asynchronous, which means `userRef.getDocument()` returns immediately, and you receive a callback only after the request completes.  If you try to access `dxUser` right after that call within your `fetchUser()` method, it will not be available, because the request isn't complete.  Given that's how async APIs work, you should only work with `dxUser` *after* the callback invoked, which usually means delaying the rendering of that data in your app (such as where your print statement is).

[Please read more here](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93) about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous and what you can expect from them.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. I pulled the fetchUser() function out to the viewWillAppear function so I called it before the view appeared. Then I did the async function to re-run viewDidLoad. Anyone else have any better suggestions?

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(true)
      fetchUser()
    }

    func fetchUser() {

      let userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

      userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
          if error != nil {
              print(error as Any)
          } else {
              self.dxUser = DxUser(dictionary: (document?.data())!)!            
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.viewDidLoad()
              }     
              self.navigationItem.title = self.dxUser.name
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Don't call `viewDidLoad`.  Call the specific code you have in `viewDidLoad` that you want re-executed.